# search group membership for a list of users

Tags: powershell

I am quite new to PowerShell and on the site.
My issue is that I found a script which I have modified. The script is working, but only partial; it is not returning all the groups. Only 4 groups and after that is displaying "....." and no other info (you can see the picture).

[image: actual output]

Basically what I want to do is the following:
I have 100 users and I need to export the group membership of these 100 users.

```
 [$users = Get-Content "D:\users.txt"
$adjob = foreach ($user in $users) {
    Get-ADUser -server "myserver" –Identity $user –Properties MemberOf
}

$adjob | Select-Object Name,@{N='Group';E={$_.MemberOf -replace '^CN=(\[^,\]+),OU=.+$','$1'}} | Format-Table -AutoSize | out-file D:\users.csv][1]
```

Thise script should return:

name
user1
user2
user3

group

group1,group2,group3,rest of the groups for each User

group1,group2,group3,rest of the groups for each User

group1,group2,group3,rest of the groups for each User

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$users = Get-Content "D:\users.txt"
$adjob = foreach ($user in $users) {
      Get-ADUser -server "myserver" –Identity $user –Properties MemberOf
}
$adjob | foreach {"`n`n";$_.name, $((($_.MemberOf -split ",")| Select-String "CN") -replace "CN=","")}
```

The output should be username and group names right below. `` "`n`n" `` Will put two blank lines after every user.

For your particular case please try this:
Enter this on PowerShell first `$FormatEnumerationLimit=-1` and then replace `Format-Table -AutoSize` in your original script with `Format-Table -AutoSize -Wrap` or `Format-List`

Comment: Thank you, very helpful. I can use some how the new script. It seems that i made an mistake, i wan to keep the actual format, everything to be in line like it is in my snapshot. My big problem was that the script wasn't give me the full membership, now the problem  was solved, but the format it should be in line for each user. I have try to format in multiple ways the result, but is not working :(

Comment: Enter this on PowerShell first `$FormatEnumerationLimit=-1` and then replace `Format-Table -AutoSize`  in your orignal script with `Format-Table  -AutoSize -Wrap` or `Format-List`

Comment: You rock!!!!! You helped me with two scripts that work like charm. Good bless you!